# iOS UITextView setText EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, ios7, utf-8, uitextview

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I set some text in 'Urdu' language

```
txtDetailLandscape.text = @"مير‎";
```

If I set some English string, it work ok.

*txtDetailLandscape* is my `UITextView` in landscape mode with weak property, while there is another `UITextView` which is working in both cases.

Really weird error, can't figure out why it is giving *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error and this problem is only in iOS7 not in iOS6.

P.S I want all utf-8 languages to display not just Urdu

Comment: It's working fine in iOS7 also. I think issue is not for that. explain elaborately.

Comment: I have two views, one for portrait and one for landscape, TextView in portrait working fine, but not textview in landscape view is not working fine(only if I use some other language). it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

check the property of the txtDetailLandscape if it is "week" then it may happen due to the release the object by ARC.
make this property as "strong" and this will works fine.